# How can I add a banner to a ServiceNow ticket to remind technicians to record time taken on solving the ticket?

Tags: servicenow

Or is there a way to stop technicians moving on until this area has been recorded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a client script which is of type [`onLoad`](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/paris-application-development/page/script/client-scripts/concept/client-scripts.html).

```
function onLoad() { 
   gs.addInfoMessage("Please record the time taken to solve the ticket");
}
```